# Why regex path in express route does not capture query strings?

Tags: node.js, regex, express, routes

```
        app.get(/\/example\/(.+)/, (req, res) => {
   const url=req.params[0]
})
```

The URL "/example/test.com?a=1" matches the given regex route, but the capture group does not capture the query string. I know I can obtain the query params using `req.query`.
But the capture group should have captured the entire `test.com?a=1`, but it only captures `test.com`.

I don't understand why this is happening. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Route strings, whether regex or simple, don't capture query strings (after the `?`). You use req.query for that, as you know

They capture parts of the URL path. Therefore, if your url were

https://example.com/a/1

you could write a regex path to capture the 1.